# Rails 6 Displaying a BLOB column as an image in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blob, ruby-on-rails-6

I've stored image files as BLOBs in a mysql database via a python script using BytesIO:

```
 with BytesIO() as f:
  rgb_img.save(f, format='JPEG', optimize=True, quality=50)
  jpeg_bytes = f.getvalue()
```

I'm now trying to retrieve and display those BLOBs in my Rails 6 environment. The column is defined in schema.rb as
`t.binary "scratcher_image"` (schema/models all generated via schema_to_scaffold gem)

I'm trying to display the images as follows:

```
<%= ('<img alt="" class="absolute inset-0 object-cover" src="data:image/jpg;base64,%s">' % Base64.encode64(s.scratcher_image)).html_safe %>
```

Except I am getting
`no implicit conversion of nil into String`

Note that `s.scratcher_image` is not nil, if I write something like `<p><%= s.scratcher_image %></p>` I get all the binary displayed on the page

Comment: Well the `Base64.encode64` seems to be receiving `nil` based on the error what happens if you add `to_s`. Also I would recommend changing your "display" to `<%= image_tag "data:image/jpeg;base64, #{Base64.encode64(s.scratcher_image.to_s)}", class: 'absolute inset-0 object-cover' %>`

Comment: I'm new to all this but I think its receiving nil because the binary data is in JPEG/Exif format which contains 00 bytes? There must be some conversion I can do to that data that allows it to be base64 encoded

Comment: `Base64` can encode null bytes so that is not the issue

Comment: oh wow i believe .to_s worked!